# Papyrus fight glitch or something

Tags: undertale

Okay. So I am at least 3 minutes into papyrus's fight and no blue attack. This is my 6th pacifist so I'm not sure what's going on. I've never been able to finish a genocide cause I refuse to kill papyrus. Why won't the blue attack happen? Is it part of the game or a glitch?

Answer (score 2):

Have you attempted either the **FIGHT** or **MERCY** option during your fight?

In my experience, many return players remember choosing to flirt with Papyrus as the trigger for the second phase of the fight. However, the Flirt dialogue isn't enough to progress the fight to the second stage - he won't do a blue attack until you've attempted either FIGHT or MERCY then SPARE, so if you continually select ACT or ITEM (like the Flirt or Insult dialogues) menu options the fight will stay on the red soul phase and never progress.